# Change kernel in a jupyter's cell using a python command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a python command to change the kernel during an evaluation of a jupyter notebook's cell, something like:

```
In[1:] #on utilise le kernel python3
       change_kernel('python3');

In[2:] #on utilise le kernel SageMath
       change_kernel('SageMath');

In[3:] #on utilise le kernel Python2
       change_kernel('Python2.7');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put this on a cell

Notebook should restart with the new kernel.

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.notebook.session.restart({kernel_name: 'python3'})
```

You can take a look at the javascript interface [session](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/b8b66332e2023e83d2ee04f83d8814f567e01a4e/notebook/static/services/sessions/session.js)

Comment: This does not work unfortunately in JupyterLab environment with `Javascript Error: Jupyter is not defined` error.